# Probability Question: 52 card deck is split into 13 piles of 4 cards each, expected value of piles of the same suit?

Tags: probability

The question was "If a 52 card deck is split into 13 piles of 4 cards each.  What is the expected value of piles with 4 cards of the same suit?"

I thought perhaps this was a problem with the tower rule (Law of Total Expectation)
E(X) = E(E(X|Y))

But there seems to be no "given" scenario in the problem.  I answered with $(13+12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1)*P($4 cards of the same suit$)$ or $(13+12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1)*(1*\frac{12}{51}*\frac{11}{50}*\frac{10}{49}$
But it seemed far too simple.

I am not quite sure how to account for the following probabilities, i.e. assuming the first deck is all hearts, what about the next being all hearts or all spades/clubs/diamonds.  How would one take these variables into account?

Comment: Is it exactly $4$ or at least $4$?  At least $4$ is easy because every hand will have a suit of at least $4$ cards.  You are expected to use the linearity of expectation-the expectation that each hand has a suit of $4$ cards is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would assess the probability that the first hand has a suit of exactly $4$ cards.  The chance it has exactly $4$ spades is $\frac {{13 \choose 4}}{52 \choose 4}$.  Now use the linearity of expectation for the expected number of hands.

Comment: The probability that a hand **of four cards** contains 4 spades is: $\tbinom{13}4/\tbinom{52}4$.  The probability that such a hand contains 4 cards of the same suit is $\tbinom 41\tbinom{13}4/\tbinom{52}4$

Comment: @GrahamKemp:  I misread it as four hands of thirteen instead of thirteen hands of four.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_k$, for any $k\in\{1,\ldots,13\}$, be the indicator function that hand $k$ contains all the same suit (that is, $X_k$ has a value of $1$ when it does, and a value of $0$ when it does not).

Since this is Bernoulli, we see that the expectation of the indicator is the probability that it equals $1$, and this probability may be determined using an hypergeometric scenario. $$\mathsf E(X_k)~=~\mathsf P(X_k{=}1)$$

The sum of these 13 indicator functions will count the hands which contain all the same suit.

Let $X=\sum_{k=1}^{13} X_k$ and use the Linearity of Expectation to evaluate $\mathsf E(X)$.